# Using SQL UNPIVOT to make a row vertical using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single row of data that I am looking to make vertical.I believe UNPIVOT is my best option, but I have been unable to get it to work. My row has the following data:

```
id | Qualifier 1  | Qualifier 2  | Qualifier 3 | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      CP              HP            TE         0000000000 1111111111 2222222222
```

I am looking to have all the qualifiers in a row with their associated value. For example, Qualifer 1 will always be linked to Value 1. It will never be associated with Value 2. I am hoping for a result that looks like:

```
 id | Qualifier | Value
 -----------------------
  1     CP       0000000000 
  1     HP       1111111111
  1     TE       2222222222
```

I have had several iterations of my code, but so far the best I have been able to come up with that works is as follows. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT ID, NUMBERS, 
FROM TABLE1
UNPIVOT
(
numbers for nums in (Value1,Value2,Value3) 
) unPiv
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `cross apply`:

```
select t.id, v.Qualifier, v.Value
from t cross apply
     (values (t.Qualifier1, t.Value1),
             (t.Qualifier2, t.Value2),
             (t.Qualifier3, t.Value3)
     ) v(Qualifier, Value);
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a strong foundation to build on. I have not worked with cross apply before so it never registered as an option.

Comment: @ChrisLombardi take a look at this article if you want an explanation on the solution [An Alternative (Better?) Method to UNPIVOT](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/)